# Community branding

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, napili

can I customize branding community? 
For example add custom value between "Text color" and "Detail text color"? 
This is posible ?

[image]

Comment: did you try clicking the icon next to branding (edit css?) you can add css rules to do so

Comment: @glls You should leave a comment explaining why you think this question is no longer a duplicate, and users can vote to reopen. I don't know about taking unilateral action here.

Comment: Sry, wasn't sure how to take action. The question is actually regarding how to add an additional option in the branding menu rather than customizing the community with CSS

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible, however, you can further customize you community with CSS. next to branding there is an Edit CSS button that allows you to further customize the appearance in your community.

[image]

[image]

With the appropriate scope, you should be able to achieve what you need

Comment: I edited picture in top.  Yes, I know it but I trying add new Value with place x on picture. This is posible ?

Comment: Edited answer as well. Sry, not possible.